# Get user shared video data from Facebook graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph api in my app. I want to get user's posted videos. When I login I get basic info. But when i query about posts i only get id in result.
My code is:

```
-(void)getPosts {

NSMutableDictionary *par = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[par setObject:@"posts" forKey:@"fields"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me"
                             parameters:par
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          )
 {
     //handle the result
     if(!error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",result);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];

}
```

Please help if I am doing wrong or missing something. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the referance from facebook dev API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/videos

you got Logged in User Video using this method:

```
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

[it's Filed object is](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/)

[image]

You need to set first Permission of **user_videos** as par doc said:

> A user access token with **user_videos** permission is required to see all videos that person is tagged in or has uploaded.

**HERE IT IS SAMPLE CODE:**

http://www.filedropper.com/fblogin

Comment: When I use this i get data =     (
    ); in response

Comment: replace you method with this above and set permission at logged in time

Comment: How i can i set permissions at login time. As I am setting permissions in viewDidLoad as, loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_likes",@"user_videos",@"user_photos"];

Comment: with above permission just add one `user_videos` with above all and yes test with user who shared a video in Facebook else you not get reprocess

Comment: check i attached sample code download from link i just update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Nitin for your time. But I am still not getting desired data. Can you please show me the whole procedure(code) for permissions, and query. I'll be gratefull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55548/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-user3587946).

Comment: /me/videos only gives the video in which person is tagged in. It will not give the video which is uploaded by user...

Comment: how to display video from Facebook pages to my IOS app?

Answer (score 1):

**1) Here  is a basic logic to get *User's uploaded* video...(shows all videos that were published to Facebook by user)**

```
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos/uploaded"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          arrFbUserUploadVideos= [result objectForKey:@"data"]; //get all data in NSMutableArray
                      }];
```

Note: This will give the video **Uploaded by the user..**

**2) and if you also want video list in which *User tag* (shows all videos use person is tagged in) in that case**

```
/* make the API call */
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              id result,
                              NSError *error
                          ) {
                              /* handle the result */
                               arrFbUserTagVideos= [result objectForKey:@"data"]; //get all data in NSMutableArray
                          }];
```

Note: This will give the video **in which user is tag..**

[**HERE IS A REFERENCE LINK:**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/videos)

Comment: how to display video from Facebook pages to my IOS app?