# Query for missing steps for Graph API call in accessing FB videos

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am working on graph api to get user's liked pages videos. I have read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ and requested for **user_action.videos** from Facebook. Now things becomes more confusing for me when i read about **1- OAuth Authentication**, **2- temporary/long-lived access token** and **3- test user** as well.

1- As i believe as per my reading that OAuth Authentication for user is not required as it is done by FB SDK automatically. Is it right and if its wrong then how to authenticate user while using FB login dialogue as there is no URLRequest call in latest FB SDK login button?

2- After login through dialogue, I am getting an access token which is an expiry token and to keep user logged into my App; I have to convert that expiry token to long-lived token for 60 days every time when token is going to expire?

3- Is there any need for creating Test User in Facebook developer portal. Is there any role of it in development?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course you need to log the user in and ask them for the permissions your app needs, that does not happen automatically.

Comment: thanks @CBroe, I've done login dialogue and asking for 'user_tagged_places' permissions on login and request for  FB submission is also made. Now i'm making a call by 
     FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" 
parameters:nil
HTTPMethod:@"GET"];     
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"%@", result);
    }]; 
button 'result' is giving me nil result :( . I've confirmed the tokens (App & API). what mistake i'm doing?

Comment: `/me/videos`, using a user access token, would be the user’s own videos that they uploaded.

Comment: i have followed the answer here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198357/get-user-shared-video-data-from-facebook-graph-api> . Now then what i should change/update?

Comment: That is about getting the user’s own uploaded or shared videos. There is no endpoint to get what videos the user liked on different pages.

Comment: @CBroe there is on the second anwer; at bottom of the above link. You may see. I Also followed the reference using  /me/videos/tagged 
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/videos but result is still nil.

Comment: Both of the answers there talk about using `/me/videos`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143474/discussion-between-muhammad-zaheer-and-cbroe).